# how to get html format from plain text of text field/view

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can i programatically converts plain text of text field/view to html format. Is there any convertor/editor which help me to convert that plain text into html format?.

Eg. In Stack Overflow we have html button (below title) which converts plain text in to html. Same thing i want to convert plain text to html.